# Thread-safe Sorted Collection

Tags: python, collections, thread-safety, sorting

Is there an implementation of a thread-safe sorted collection in Python?
[Python's docs](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) reference [SortedCollection](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) but I'm not sure if it's thread-safe (is it?)
If there is no such implementation - how would you implement it?

Comment: Actually I don't see why Python doesn't come with such a class built in...

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the code, it does not appear to be thread safe.  To use it from multiple threads the application code that accesses it should be guarded with semaphore locks.

If you want to make the SortedCollection class thread safe, you could write a decorator function.

It would look something like this:

SortedCollection:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.mysemaphore = threading.Semaphore()

def guard(func):
    def guarded(*args, **kwds):
        self.mysemaphore.acquire()
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwds)
        finally:
            self.mysemaphore.release()

return guarded

# edit the class, applying the decorator to its methods.
@guard
def unsafeFunc(self, a, b, c):
    ''' do work here'''
```

**EDIT**

Don't make the mistake of thinking that a threadsafe data structure will make your application code thread safe.  If you perform multiple operations on a SortedCollection, all of those operations need to be guarded by a lock.

Even if SortedCollection is threadsafe, the following code would not be:

```
slist.insert(1)
slist.insert(2)
```

It is possible that another thread could insert an item in between those 2 statements.  You will need to guard within your application code.  If you add this to your application code, you will not need to modify the SortedCollection to be thread safe.

```
semaphore2.acquire()

try:
    slist.insert(1)
    slist.insert(2)
finally:
    semaphore2.release()
```

Comment: wouldn't the func return block the semaphore release?

Comment: @eduardocereto From the docs: `The finally clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other clause of the try statement is left via a break, continue or return statement.`

Comment: Why use `threading.Semaphore`? isn't `threading.Lock` enough?

Comment: Just to state it again, "threadsafe" simply means that calls from multiple threads cannot corrupt the internals of a data structure,  calls from different threads may still be executed in arbitrary order. Btw, in modern Python you lock like this: `with mylock: dostuff()`.

Comment: using a global `mysemaphore`, wouldn't you wrongfully lock between different instances of `SortedCollection`? How could you do this per instance?

Comment: if you decorate `_delkey` method which uses `_setkey` method which also should be decorated, wouldn't that cause a deadlock?

Comment: @Jonathan, you are correct.  I wasn't very clear.  I was trying to keep the answer more concise.  I edited it to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Jonathan, that would cause a deadlock.  In some cases you might want to manually manage the locks.  In that case I would just modify `_delkey` so it does not depend on `_setkey`.

Answer (score 2):

The *collections.OrderedDict* class is not threadsafe for updates.  You can do concurrent reads, but locks are needed for writes.  For an example of how to use locks with *OrderedDict*, see the source for [functools.lru_cache()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/functools.py).

Answer (score 1):

Python is different from Java: If a class has not specified its threading behavior in the docs, it is safe to assume that it is not thread-safe.

Python is not written with threading in mind. Even today, multi threading is really a second class citizen as only a single thread is active at all times (which does not prevent most data race issues). It is called Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).

If a class or a data structure is not build for concurrency, you have to protect access to it by an [external lock](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects)

Comment: That's actually not at all different from Java. In Java if nothing is mentioned about threading it's safe to assume that it's not thread safe. Though contrary to python you get thread-safe collections - python's sadly lacking in that regard :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [heapq](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html?highlight=heapq#module-heapq) module to maintain a sorted list. By the power of the GIL all calls to C Extensions are atomic (in CPython, unless the extension explicitly releases the lock) and therefore `heappush` and friends are thread-safe.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

class Heap:

    def __init__(self):
        self._heap = []

    def push(self, x):
        heappush(self._heap, x)

    def pop(self):
        return heappop(self.heap)
```

Comment: ... except that `heapq` is _not_ a C extension!!  `heapq` is implemented in pure python.  Check out [the code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py).  From a quick look, `heapq` definitely does  _not_ look thread safe!

Comment: I should also add that, although the `heapq` functions themselves certainly are not thread safe, you can use the [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module's [PriorityQueue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue), which _is_ thread safe and uses `heapq` internally.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic operations are always thread-safe in python. You only need to synchronize if the operations are not atomic. The GIL only ever allows one atomic operation at a time, no matter the number of threads. Multi-processing in python is another matter.